# how can you count the "!" but not periods, spaces, or commas?

Tags: c

Here is my code.  It works for almost all strings...except for the ones with exclamation marks.  I want to count the exclamation marks as a character but not the spaces, commas, or periods.  How do I do this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    
    char str[51];
    fgets(str, 51, stdin);
    
    int length = strlen(str), count = 0, i;
    
    for (i = 0; i < length-1; i++) {
        if (str[i] != ',' && str[i] != ' ' && str[i] != '.') {
            count++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: An exclamation mark is never a space, comma, or period. How do you get this?

Comment: I assume your exclamation mark is always the last in the string?

Answer (score 1):

The last character of the string is not being counted.
To go through all the string you can use i < length in the for loop